# XHR error (404) loading angular2/forms

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to use angular2 in a non-npm mode(running a tomcat server) . The server side using java-spring starting off the index page thats loading the dependent scripts.

On my index.html the imports are as,

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/http.dev.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/router.dev.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/testing.dev.js"></script>
```

The typescripts are consfigured on System.js as

```
<script>
    System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript',
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
        packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}}
    });
    System.import('app/main.browser')
          .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Rest of the module references work except forms, importing the modules as,

```
import { NgModule } from "angular2/core";
import { CommonModule } from "angular2/common";
import {
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
} from "angular2/forms";
```

On loading tine index file I am getting the below exception:

```
angular2-polyfills.js:1243 Error: XHR error (404) loading http://localhost:8080/angular2/forms
    Error loading http://localhost:8080/angular2/forms as "angular2/forms" from http://localhost:8080/app/schema-form/schema-form.module.ts
    at o (https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js:4:12694)
    at XMLHttpRequest.I.s.onreadystatechange [as _onreadystatechange] (https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js:4:13219)
    at Zone.run (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2-polyfills.js:1243:24)
    at XMLHttpRequest.zoneBoundFn (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2-polyfills.js:1220:26)
```

Any pointers on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

i think you should import from `@angular/core` not `angular2/core`.now its @angular/core so change it.

Comment: @angular is working, i am including the angular dependency as     "@angular/core": "^2.0.0",
I got it working changing the @angular/forms to  @angular/http, not sure why for 2.0.0-beta.9 it's registered that way.

Comment: well you haven't mentioned you are getting problem in you http. And there was no code to check out that. @angular/forms and @angluar/http are not related. both are different things. If you keep both then also it will work. we used to import form angular2/core now we only use @angular. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct, for people who have the same problem in the future! :)